# Angular calendar sheduler event's height not properly displayed in Firefox

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I work with angular-calendar-scheduler and the events is displayed properly in chrome and brave browser. But in Firefox, the height is not displayed correctly.
I don't know if this is a big issue or something about Firefox's settings, so thanks for the help.

Also, a small issue is that in the browser that it work (like chrome), when I change the hours, I need to hover, and then the height it displayed. it not displayed without hover the event.

Here are 2 pic from chrome and Firefox.

Image from chrome, height displayed correctly

[image: 1]

Image from firefox, height not displayed correctly

[image: 2]

Comment: If this is specific to a library it would be best you contact the author via GitHub by submitting an issue.

Comment: I submitted the issue, but i want to know if there is a solution here. the issue can take much time.